# Re-setting an istringstream object

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, istringstream

When I run this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.size(); i++) {

                iss.str(indexArray.at(i));
                iss>>one;
                iss>>two;
                iss>>three;
                cout<<one<<" "<<two<<" "<<" "<<three<<" "<<"\n";
}
```

the istreamstream (iss) remains the same with every iteration. (The file is read into an vector at the beginning of the program. Yes, I checked to make sure the array had the corresponding data.)

In other words, I get this output:

```
12345 1  0 
12345 1  0 
12345 1  0
```

whereas the file/vector actually says:

```
12345 1 0
12346 1 25
12543 1 50
```

I've tried various traces and can't pinpoint the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `iss.clear();` before `iss.str(indexArray.at(i));` to clear the EOF flag when reusing `istringstream`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!